# Ordenação de Chaves usando OrderedDict?

Tags: python, dicionário

O código abaixo mostra que os elementos são ordenados com chaves ímpar de forma decrescente e os com chaves par de forma crescente, mas não estão sendo ordenados conforme a regra.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

class Produto ():
    def __init__(self, nome, preco):
      self.__nome = nome
      self.__preco = preco

    def __str__(self):
        return "{!s} - R${:.2f}".format(self.__nome, self.__preco)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    t = int(input())

    # Informe seu código aqui
    estoque = OrderedDict()

    for i in range(1, t+1):
        chave, nome, valor = input().split()
        prod = Produto(nome, float(valor)) 

        estoque[int(chave)] = prod 

    for k, v in estoque.items():
        if k % 2 != 0:
            reversed(estoque.keys())
        else:
            sorted(estoque.keys())     

    [print("{:d}={!s}".format(k,v)) for k, v in estoque.items()]
```

Entrada:

```
6
1 celular 999.99
2 computador 2499.90
3 tv 1299.50
4 drive 149.50
5 usb 120.75
6 teclado 450.31
```

Minha Saída:

```
1=celular - R$999.99
2=computador - R$2499.90
3=tv - R$1299.50
4=drive - R$149.50
5=usb - R$120.75
6=teclado - R$450.31
```

Saída Esperada:

```
5=usb - R$120.75
3=tv - R$1299.50
1=celular - R$999.99
2=computador - R$2499.90
4=drive - R$149.50
6=teclado - R$450.31
```

Comment: Tanto a função `reversed` quanto a `sorted` **retornam** a sequência classificada; você ignorou o retorno das duas no seu código, portanto efetivamente você não ordenou sua sequência. Para facilitar, recomendo em separar duas sequências distintas, do que é par do que é ímpar.

Comment: Flávio, se alguma resposta resolveu seu problema, você pode marcar uma delas como aceita. Entenda importância disso nesse link: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 0):

Então, não faz muito sentido este ordem, mas se é o caso, segue o código:

```
class Produto:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = self.show_weird_order(self.prod())

    def prod(self):
        estoque = []
        t = int(input(": "))
        for i in range(t):
            nome, valor = input().split()
            estoque.append((nome, float(valor)))
        print('\n')
        return estoque

    def show_weird_order(self, estoque):
        for i in range(1, len(estoque)+1):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                index = i*-1
                print(f"{len(estoque)+(index+1)} = {estoque[index][0]} - R${round(estoque[index][1], 2)}")
        for j in range(len(estoque)):
            if (j+1) % 2 == 0:
                print(f"{j+1} = {estoque[j][0]} - R${round(estoque[j][1], 2)}")
```

Quando chamar a classe:

```
exemplo = Produto()
```

Passarei:

```
6
celular 999.99
computador 2499.90
tv 1299.50
drive 149.50
usb 120.75
teclado 450.31
```

Retornará:

```
5 = usb - R$120.75
3 = tv - R$1299.5
1 = celular - R$999.99
2 = computador - R$2499.9
4 = drive - R$149.5
6 = teclado - R$450.31
```

Qualquer coisa, é só personalizar conforme a tua necessidade.